# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null in javascript code when getting local ip Address of computer

Tags: javascript

i am getting local ip of computer but an error occurred
any body help to resolve this issue
thanks

```js
window.RTCPeerConnection = window.RTCPeerConnection || window.mozRTCPeerConnection || window.webkitRTCPeerConnection; // compatibility for Firefox and chrome
var pc = new RTCPeerConnection({ iceServers: [] }), noop = function () { };
pc.createDataChannel('');//create a bogus data channel
pc.createOffer(pc.setLocalDescription.bind(pc), noop); // create offer and set local description
pc.onicecandidate = function (ice) {
  if (ice && ice.candidate && ice.candidate.candidate) {
    var myIP = /([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}|[a-f0-9]{1,4}(:[a-f0-9]{1,4}){7})/.exec(ice.candidate.candidate)[1];
    console.log('my IP: ', myIP);
    pc.onicecandidate = noop;
  }
};
```

Comment: Your regex didn’t match. It returned null. And then you tried to access `[1]` on it. Either `ice.candidate.candidate` isn’t what you think it is or there’s a problem with your regex.

Comment: ray hatfield can you help that how to match the regix

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not getting IP address in ice.candidate.candidate, you can try to print in the console logs and check

You would be getting UUID.local, You can confirm it once.

If that's the case, you can find the same it in this link
https://groups.google.com/g/discuss-webrtc/c/y22EShk84iA

Which redirects you to https://bloggeek.me/psa-mdns-and-local-ice-candidates-are-coming/

Comment: so what is the simplest way to get IPv4 address of  computer i tried different method like    
  but using all mehtods return internet providers ip not my personal computer IPv4 address. please help any to solve the issue. Thanks

Comment: using these methods    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.getJSON("http://jsonip.appspot.com?callback=?", function (data) {
            $("#ipv").html('IP Address IS:' + data.ip);

        })
            
    })

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("https://ipv4.myip.addr.space/ajaxlookup")
            .done(function (data) {
                $("#ip").html(data);
            })
    })

Comment: $scope.getip = function () {
        //$.getJSON('https://ipapi.co/' + $('.ip').val() + + $location.host()+'/json', function (data) {
        //    $scope.ip = data.ip;
        //    alert($scope.ip);
        //////});
        fetch("https://api.ipify.org/?format=json")
            .then(results => results.json())
            .then(data => console.log(data.ip));
        //$.getJSON("http://jsonip.com?callback=?", function (response) {
        //    $("#ip").text(response.ip);
        //})
    }

Comment: all these mthods returns internet providers public ip not my personal computer's IPv4 address. i want to get IPv4 address from client side language like angularjs ,javascript,jquery etc